# How to get the img elements from within a div tag using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my HTML:

```
<div id="mover">
    <img src="images/building3.jpg" width="330" height="150" />
    <img src="images/building5.jpg" width="330" height="150" />
    <img src="images/building1.jpg" width="330" height="150" />
    <img src="images/building4.jpg" width="330" height="150" />
</div>
```

Using:

```
document.getelementById("mover");
```

only gives me this div, how can I get all the images from this div using JavaScript?

Comment: `document.getelementById("mover").getElementsByTagName('img')` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {   
  $("div#mover").find('img').each(function() {
      alert($(this));
  })
});

Comment: To those voting to reopen, can I ask *why you're voting to reopen?* What saves this question that I, and others, have yet to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if this works out for you:

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="mover">
    <img src="images/building3.jpg" width="330" height="150" />
    <img src="images/building5.jpg" width="330" height="150" />
    <img src="images/building1.jpg" width="330" height="150" />
    <img src="images/building4.jpg" width="330" height="150" />
</div>


<script>

var imgs = document.getElementById("mover").getElementsByTagName("img");

for (i in imgs) {
    if (parseInt(i) > -1) { // check if it is an integer        
        alert(document.getElementById("mover").getElementsByTagName("img")[i].src);
    }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```